# "Argument Not Optional" VBA Excel SUB

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on some VBA code and I'm getting an

> Argument not optional

error. I looked through some of the other answers to this problem and they didn't seem to answer my problem.

The code gets stuck at the first iteration of `Sub Finding_number ()` which is what is confusing me. I'm not passing any arguments to or from that Sub so why the error?

**my code**:

```
Sub Pedal_Actuations_per_hour()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim average_actuations As Single

counter = 1    
Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = False    
    Finding_number
    average_actuations = (average_actuations + Pedal_actuations()) / counter
    counter = counter + 1    
Loop

Range("J2").Value = average_actuations    

End Sub


Sub Finding_number()

    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1        
    Range("E2").Select

    Do While index = 1
        If ActiveCell.Value = 121 Then
            index = 0
        End If

        Range.Offset (1)
    Loop

End Sub

Function Pedal_actuations() As Integer

Dim time_sum As Single
Dim index As Integer

index = 1
time_sum = 0    
Do While time_sum < 1            
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = 0 Then 
        date_number = Int(ActiveCell(, -2).Value)
        ActiveCell(, 6).Value = ActiveCell(, -2).Value - date_number
        ActiveCell(, 7).Value = Abs(ActiveCell(, 6).Value - ActiveCell(2, 6)) *24 
    Else
        index = 0
    End If

    Pedal_actuations = Pedal_actuations + 1
    time_sum = time_sum + ActiveCell(, 7).Value                
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: `Range.Offset (1)`  is wrong, doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The error is here `Range.Offset (1)`.  You are not stating which cell to offset nor are you telling it what to do with that cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to avoid using `Select`, `ActiveCell` , Etc...
Instead use referenced object as `Sheets` and `Range`s.

```
Sub Finding_number()

    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("E2")

    Do While index = 1
        If Rng.Value = 121 Then
            index = 0
        End If

        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

The shorter version below, will give you the same result:

```
Sub Finding_number()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("E2")

    Do While Rng.Value <> 121
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does Range work with all the same capabilities as Activecell but is more efficient/faster? For example, you see in the function of my code I use activecell to perform certain things. Can I do all of that but with a range object and just do Rng(, 6).value = ... ?

Comment: @VincentCeyssens you can read more about the `Range` object here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx . the second part, I think you mean `Offset` , right ? the correct syntax is `Rng.Offset(,6).Value`

Answer (score 2):

It's likely

```
Range.Offset (1)
```

You might want to change your code into something like

```
Sub Finding_number()

    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E2")

    Do While index = 1
        If rng.Value = 121 Then index = 0
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

So, what went wrong?

You wanted to work with the Range that you selected earlier in your code, then move on to the next Cell and so on.

What you likely wanted to do was

```
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

This offsets the to the cell under our current selected cell, then selects it.

**However:** its better practice to just define and set a range object with

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("E2")
```

and then set it to the next cell in after each loop with

```
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
```

Finally, to further improve your sub, consider if you really need your `index`-Variable. Here's a shot without it

```
Sub Finding_number()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E2")

    Do While Not rng.Value = 121
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```